# Pegar o número de dias ativos de um usuário no SEDE

Tags: suporte, usuarios

Estou tentando pegar o número de dias ativos que um usuário tem através do [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/). Na verdade quero calcular a reputação média por dia (oficialmente) ativo do usuário. Alguém sabe como obter isso?

Quero esta informação:

[image: Número de visitas]

Isto não tem na tabela de usuários e precisa ser calculada de alguma forma.

Comment: O ideal não é perguntar no SOpt?

Comment: Não sei :) Em geral quando é algo do SEDE perguntamos aqui, não? Inclusive porque a pergunta assim no SOpt acho que deveria ser fechada :D

Comment: @CypherPotato creio que nao, pq ele nao ta com problema pra fazer a query, e sim achar uma documentação de uma ferramenta específica aqui da rede que diga onde tá isso. Lá inclusive acho que seria fechada kkkkk

Comment: Eu fecharia... :D

Comment: [Neste FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67402/401803), na descrição da medalha "Fanatic", é dito que "*The exact amount of activity required to count as a visit is not public information*". E [nas queries que encontrei](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=average+rep+per+day), todas calculam pelo total de dias (da criação da conta até a data atual), provavelmente é o mais próximo que dá pra chegar. De qualquer forma, nem sempre se ganha reputação no dia que é ativo, a pessoa pode responder e não ganhar votos num dia, e nem abrir o site e ganhar votos em outro.

Comment: @hkotsubo é, então complica, mas eu acho que ainda dá pra fazer uma *query* pra obter isso, só não acho que vale o esforço, não será tão simples :D E talvez dê pra fazer até mais precisa que só saber se a pessoa visitou o site. Eu não me preocupo com a questão de ter voto porque pro meu critério esse dia ela teve 0 votos. Dá pra adotar outros critérios.